# Find all the minimal values on a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of tuples. Each tuple's element 0 is a numeric value. I want to find all the tuples with the minimal value in element 0. For example:

```
l = [(2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (1, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (1, 'f')]
l.sort()
i = 1
while i < len(l):
    if l[i - 1][0] != l[i][0]:
        break
i += 1
print(l[:i])
```

would give me what I want:

```
[(1, 'b'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'f')]
```

My question is (could be three different answers): what is the Code Golf/fastest/most Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Code golf, fastest, and most Pythonic way are three different questions.

Comment: @kaya3 I did say "could be three different answers" didn't I. We are gonna debate if I should have said "my questions are?"

Comment: I'm not debating your grammar; I'm pointing out that you've posted three questions as one question, which means people may downvote, or vote to close as "needs more focus". I have done neither, for the record, but I think the question could still be improved by focusing on just one aspect. There is a separate SE site for code golf ( https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ), by the way.

Comment: @kaya3 I am interested in any possible answers to _any_ of the questions, but I don't want to, nor is there a serious need as far as I can see, to literally post the same scenario in three separate questions. To say the least I never intended to post this as a code golf contest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `min`. The time complexity is O(*n*) and it uses O(1) auxiliary space (i.e. not including the space for the output list).

```py
from operator import itemgetter

min_key, _ = min(lst, key=itemgetter(0))
result = [ (k, v) for k, v in lst if k == min_key ]
```

Comment: Can you expand on how this is O(n) please ?

Comment: Because `min` iterates through the list once and does O(1) work for each element, and then the list comprehension afterwards iterates through the list once and does O(1) work for each element.

Comment: But ``min`` requires to iterate over the whole list to find the minimum and the list comprehension also iterates over ``lst`` right ? I don't grasp the intuition here

Comment: You're saying "but" but you are actually just repeating what I said. Both `min` and the list comprehension iterate over the list once, and each does O(1) work per element.

Comment: Was there a reason for explicitly `key=itemgetter(0)`?  I think min defaults to use tuple[0]?

Comment: @jingx For this case, the second components of the tuples are strings, so you don't need a key. In general, the other components might be objects that don't support comparison operations. But good point!

Answer (score 3):

```py
>>> [v for v in l if v[0] == min(l, key = lambda k: k[0])[0]]
[(1, 'b'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'f')]
```

Let's break it out:
`min(l, key = lambda k: k[0])` - Will give us the tuple with the minimum integer value.
Adding `[0]` will give us the value of the minimum integer, and then by running on the list using `list comprehension` we'll get all the tuples witht the minimum value.

*P.S*
It's best to calculate the minimum value before using the list comprehension, so you won't calculate it every time (but it's less Pythonic in my opinion :) ):

```py
>>> min_value = min(l, key = lambda k: k[0])[0]
>>> [v for v in l if v[0] == min_value]
[(1, 'b'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'f')]
```

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily O(n^2) since it computes the minimum value again on every iteration.

Comment: I know and I added an explanation to the post. I still think that to small lists it's more "Pythonic" to use one line :)

Comment: being pythonic is not about using fewer lines IMO

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid sorting alltogether using one pass over your list:

```
l = [(2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (1, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (1, 'f')]

v = l[0]
r = [v]
mk = v[0]
for v in l[1:]:
    key, val = v
    if key < mk:
        mk = key
        r = [v]
    elif key == mk:
        r.append(v)

print(r)
```

---

Not sure its smarter - but you skip some comparisons using:

```
l = [(2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (1, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (1, 'f')]
l.sort()
i = 1
k = l[0][0]
for e in l[1:]:    # 1 less element iterated
    if e[0] != k:  # cache the lookup value 
        break
    i += 1

print(l[:i])
```

Comment: Technically, this isn't one pass since slicing the list in `l[1:]` is another pass. It should be more efficient to just iterate over `l` and do the unnecessary comparison against the first element.

Comment: @kaya the list slice  - assuming all elements have the minimal value, might touch all elements - BUT - generally this wont be the case. The slicing only iterates a few elements of the list if you so will and the whole is ruled by n*log(n) of sorting. The problem is more that you copy lists around needlessly - thats why I put it last - the first one  only ever touches each element once, creates a minimal output list (maybe several times)  - your solution using min() and a list comprehension might far better depending on the data you put in.

Comment: The slice is not lazily evaluated; it constructs a whole new list of length n-1 where the original list had length n. The n log n time taken to sort will dominate, of course.